# If SE site foo.com exists, could foo.stackexchange.com redirect to it?

Tags: feature-request, usability, subdomains

I wanted some feedback on Windows 10 upgrades (basically, whether a free upgrade from 7 to 10 is desirable), so I went to superuser.stackexchange.com, which doesn't exist... so I went to what I should have typed in the first place, superuser.com.

For sites that have a URL of /[-\w]+.com/, would it be possible to redirect all foo.stackexchange.com sites to foo.com?

Comment: Jonathan, is this what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730298/redirect-any-sub-domain-to-a-page-on-main-domain

Comment: @HackerKarma That's a hack... Not a real thing. :/

Comment: Here is another one: http://serverfault.com/questions/229809/redirect-subdomain-example-org-to-somethingelse-com-hidden-to-the-user

Comment: @Zizouz212 how would else one can achieve then... the other link shared above uses DNS setting..

Comment: There is a precedent: http://mathoverflow.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hey! That's MathOverflow.net! Why the .net?

Comment: @Zizouz212 MO is a   special case: it began as a SE 1.0 site in 2009, and the founders picked .net presumably to emphasize the non-profit nature of the project. They eventually migrated to SE 2.0 network in 2013, but maintain some measure of independence. See also: http://mathoverflow.org/about/